# Wordpress and bootstrap not properly working

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using wordpress and on some of my pages I'd like to get some nice bootstrap forms up and running but the style messes up. If I paste my code and try it locally it all works fine. I think the stylesheets are colliding or something? How can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.3.88.113/bootstrap-select.css">
<style>
body {
padding-top: 70px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://192.3.88.113/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="lunchBegins">Lunch (Begins search):</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select id="lunchBegins" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Please select a lunch ...">
<option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
<option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
<option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
<option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
<option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var mySelect = $('#first-disabled2');
$('#special').on('click', function () {
mySelect.find('option:selected').prop('disabled', true);
mySelect.selectpicker('refresh');
});
$('#special2').on('click', function () {
mySelect.find('option:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
mySelect.selectpicker('refresh');
});
$('#basic2').selectpicker({
liveSearch: true,
maxOptions: 1
});
});
</script>
```

How it SHOULD look:
[image]

How it ends up looking on my wordpress page:[image]

Comment: It's because of the JQuery short variable. You'll need to change every short reference to JQuery to the long one. See this: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Unfortunetely after reading that twice I still can't get it to work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: It's definitely because of the jquery short variable. I guarantee you. Search for it over at Wordpress support

Comment: Ok I got it to work but now it messes up my theme on the page

Comment: Probably because the css styles are being overridden or similar. If it works with the default theme supplied with wordpress (check that it does), try fixing your theme for it to work. Bootstrap generally isn't always 100% compatible out the box with wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if this working. Regards.

HTML

```
<select data-live-search="true"  title="Please select a lunch" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow test">
  <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
  <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
  <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/hEfDkHBFyU)

I will update my answer if it not working.